# is it a correct method to set a cookie funtion?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I was wondering if following function is a proper way of setting new cookie.

```
function setCookie() 
{
    var value='tackoverhide';
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    time += 3600 * 1000;
    now.setTime(time);
    document.cookie ='tackoverhide='+ value +'; expires=' + now.toUTCString() + '; path=/';
}
```

Comment: how can i set a cookie?

Comment: Why you have asp.net as a tag for this question? do want to set it using javascript or asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code snippet for setting cookie using JavaScript. It's almost the same as your function without minor mistakes.

```
function setCookie() {
    var name = 'tackoverhide';
    var value = 'tackoverhide';
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = 1;
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (hours*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; " + expires;
}
```